# How do I install a script to run anywhere from the command line?

Tags: python, linux, command-line, installation

If I have a basic Python script, with it's hashbang and what-not in place, so that from the terminal on Linux I can run

```
/path/to/file/MyScript [args]
```

without executing through the interpreter or any file extensions, and it will execute the program.

So would I install this script so that I can type simply

```
MyScript [args]
```

anywhere in the system and it will run? Can this be implemented for all users on the system, or must it be redone for each one? Do I simply place the script in a specific directory, or are other things necessary?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How do I make a python script executable?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27494758/how-do-i-make-a-python-script-executable)

Answer (score 42, accepted):

The best place to put things like this is `/usr/local/bin`.

This is the normal place to put custom installed binaries, and should be early in your `PATH`.

Simply copy the script there (probably using `sudo`), and it should work for any user.

Comment: Or, uglier but sometimes useful, add an arbitrary directory to $PATH.

Comment: You'd either have to mess with an important global setting that you __really__ don't want to mess up or add to user's settings individually.

Comment: +1 for recommending `/usr/local/bin`. Make sure to make the scripts executable too! `sudo chmod 744 /usr/local/bin/yourscript` should do it.

Comment: how is this different from using the `-m` flag in python? The description of such as a flag says thats the python way to do it? `Searches sys.path for the named module and runs the corresponding .py file as a script.`

Comment: @CharlieParker Basically, they're the same except for what you have to type to run them. It's just about what you want / need the user experience to be.

Answer (score 28):

### Walkthrough of making a python script available anywhere:

**Make a python script:**

```
cd /home/el/bin
touch stuff.py
chmod +x stuff.py
```

**Find out where your python is:**

```
which python
/usr/bin/python
```

Put this code in there:

```
#!/usr/bin/python
print "hi"
```

**Run in it the same directory:**

```
python stuff.py
```

**Go up a directory and it's not available:**

```
cd ..
stuff.py

-bash: stuff.py: command not found
```

**Not found!  It's as we expect, add the file path of the python file to the $PATH**

```
vi ~/.bashrc
```

**Add the file:**

```
export PATH=$PATH:/home/el/bin
```

**Save it out, re apply the .bashrc, and retry**

```
source ~/.bashrc
```

**Try again:**

```
cd /home/el
stuff.py
```

**Prints:**

```
hi
```

The trick is that the bash shell knows the language of the file via the shebang.

Comment: how is this different from using the `-m` flag in python? The description of such as a flag says thats the python way to do it? `Searches sys.path for the named module and runs the corresponding .py file as a script.`

Answer (score 12):

you can also use `setuptools` (https://pypi.org/project/setuptools/)

1. your script will be:

```
def hi():
    print("hi")
```

(suppose the file name is `hello.py`)

2. also add `__init__.py` file next to your script (with nothing in it).
3. add `setup.py` script, with the content:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python3

import setuptools

install_requires = [
        'WHATEVER PACKAGES YOU NEED GOES HERE'
        ]

setuptools.setup(
    name="some_utils",
    version="1.1",
    packages=setuptools.find_packages(),
    install_requires=install_requires,
    entry_points={
        'console_scripts': [
            'cool_script = hello:hi',
        ],
    },
    include_package_data=True,
    )
```

4. you can now run `python setup.py develop` in this folder
5. then from anywhere, run `cool_script` and your script will run.

Comment: This does not work, it shows a command not found error.

Comment: @Destaq you should have your venv active when running the command

Comment: best answer here, cf https://python-packaging.readthedocs.io/en/latest/command-line-scripts.html

Answer (score 11):

Just create `~/bin` and put `export PATH=$PATH:$HOME/bin` in your bashrc/profile. Don't mess with the system, it *will* bite you back, trust me.

Few more things (relevant to the question but not part of the answer):

1. The other way `export PATH=$HOME/bin:$PATH` is NOT safe, for bash will will look into your `~/bin` folder for executables, and if their name matches with other executables in your original `$PATH` you will be surprised by unexpected/non working command execution.
2. Don't forget to `chmod+x` when you save your script in `~/bin`.
3. Be aware of what you are putting in your `~/bin` folder, if you are just testing something or working on unfinished script, its always better to use ./$SCRIPT_NAME from your `CWD` to execute the script than putting it under `~/bin`.

Comment: Use `$HOME`, not `/home/$USER`.  And personally, I put `$HOME/bin` at the front of my `$PATH` precisely so I *can* override other commands.

Comment: thanks for pointing out `$HOME`. But kindly allow me to disagree with your second point. You _know_ what you are doing when you put ~/bin before $PATH, many (if not most) people don't know about the implications of these mechanism.

Comment: I see your point.  On the other hand, putting something in $Home/bin and having it quietly not work could be even more confusing.  Perhaps one could have one directory at the front of $PATH for deliberate overrides, and another at the end for other personal commands (with names carefully chosen to avoid collisions).  I just now thought of that, and I'm not sure how good an idea it is.  Bottom line: $PATH management is non-trivial.

Comment: Another thought: sometimes the answer to "people don't know about the implications" is to teach them.

Comment: @Keith : agreed, $PATH management is non-trivial and must be exercised with caution. As for teaching people the implications of such non-triviality, I believe the 1st point of my answer and our comments will lead anyone with sufficient curiosity into more detailed and authoritative sources of Bash architecture. So I guess we _are_ teaching them, indirectly.

Comment: Is there a way to do this automatically with setuptools?

Comment: how is this different from using the `-m` flag in python? The description of such as a flag says thats the python way to do it? `Searches sys.path for the named module and runs the corresponding .py file as a script.`

Answer (score 9):

The quick answer is to [`symlink`](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Symbolic_link) your script to any directory included in your system `$PATH`.

The long answer is described below with a walk through example, (this is what I normally do):

a) Create the script e.g. `$HOME/Desktop/myscript.py`:

```
#!/usr/bin/python
print("Hello Pythonista!")
```

b) Change the permission of the script file to make it executable:

`$ chmod +x myscript.py`

c) Add a customized directory to the `$PATH` (see why in the notes below) to use it for the user's scripts:

`$ export PATH="$PATH:$HOME/bin"`

d) Create a symbolic link to the script as follows:

`$ ln -s $HOME/Desktop/myscript.py $HOME/bin/hello`

Notice that `hello` (can be anything) is the name of the command that you will use to invoke your script.

Note:

i) The reason to use `$HOME/bin` instead of the `/usr/local/bin` is to separate the local scripts from those of other users (if you wish to) and other installed stuff.

ii) To create a symlink you should use the complete correct path, i.e.

`$HOME/bin` GOOD   `~/bin` NO GOOD!

Here is a complete example:

```
 $ pwd
 ~/Desktop
 $ cat > myscript.py << EOF
 > #!/usr/bin/python
 > print("Hello Pythonista!")
 > EOF
 $ export PATH="$PATH:$HOME/bin"
 $ ln -s $HOME/Desktop/myscript.py $HOME/bin/hello
 $ chmod +x myscript.py
 $ hello
Hello Pythonista!
```

Comment: how is this different from using the `-m` flag in python? The description of such as a flag says thats the python way to do it? `Searches sys.path for the named module and runs the corresponding .py file as a script.`

Answer (score 8):

Just create symbolic link to your script in /usr/local/bin/:

```
sudo ln -s /path/to/your/script.py /usr/local/bin/script
```

Comment: This should be the answer in my opinion.  /usr is for stuff like this,  there's no messing with PATH, and the actual script can live anywhere you want.  Nice and simple, yet effective.

Comment: This is the way. No messing with $PATH. Quick and efficient.

Answer (score 5):

Putting the script somewhere in the PATH (like `/usr/local/bin`) is a good solution, but this *forces* all the users of your system to use/see your script.

Adding an alias in `/etc/profile` could be a way to do what you want allowing the users of your system to undo this using the `unalias` command.  The line to be added would be:

```
alias MyScript=/path/to/file/MyScript
```

Comment: True, but this is the standard. If this is an important distinction, it's up to the system administrator to put policy in place to show/hide executable directories (like with `sbin`).

Answer (score 4):

i find a simple alias in my `~/.bash_profile` or `~/.zshrc` is the easiest:

`alias myscript="python path/to/my/script.py"`

Answer (score 3):

Type `echo $PATH` in a shell. Those are the directories searched when you type `command`, so put it in one of those.

Edit: Apparently don't use `/usr/bin`, use `/usr/local/bin`

Comment: No, please do not use /usr/bin! Use /usr/local/bin for these purposes.

Comment: Agreed, this is quite unadvisable. Go with /usr/local/bin instead

Answer (score 0):

Acording to [FHS](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Filesystem_Hierarchy_Standard), the `/usr/local/bin/` is the good place for custom scripts. 
I prefer to make them `755` `root:root`, after copying them there.