# How do I make a python script executable?

Tags: python, command-line

How can I run a python script with my own command line name like `myscript` without having to do `python myscript.py` in the terminal?

---

<sub>See also: [./xx.py: line 1: import: command not found](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22275350) .</sub>

Comment: What OS do you want do this on?

Comment: Mac OS X 10.10 Yosemite

Comment: See also: [python - setup.py and adding file to /bin/ - Stack Overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4840182/setup-py-and-adding-file-to-bin/35896132#35896132) for detailed instruction on the setuptools `console_scripts` method.

Answer (score 143, accepted):

1. Add a shebang line to the top of the script:

   `#!/usr/bin/env python`
2. Mark the script as executable:

   `chmod +x myscript.py`
3. Add the dir containing it to your `PATH` variable. (If you want it to stick, you'll have to do this in `.bashrc` or `.bash_profile` in your home dir.)

   `export PATH=/path/to/script:$PATH`

Comment: still cant run by my name 'square': -bash: /usr/bin/square: No such file or directory

Comment: My program is called square and i have exported the dir in PATH

Comment: @bingo14 What is the output of `echo $PATH`? And the absolute path to your script?

Comment: It is: /usr/local/bin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin:/opt/X11/bin:/usr/local/git/bin:/Development/adt-bundle/sdk/platform-tools:/Development/adt-bundle/sdk/tools

Comment: And where does your script reside?

Comment: So that needs to be added to your path, like I showed in point 3 in my answer.

Comment: Doesn't work for scripts that have dependencies our other scripts + resources they require.

Comment: If you get an error `env: python\r: No such file or directory` it's because the python script has windows line endings. You need to follow: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19425857/env-python-r-no-such-file-or-directory

Answer (score 85):

The best way, which is cross-platform,  is to create `setup.py`, define an entry point in it and install with `pip`.

Say you have the following contents of `myscript.py`:

```
def run():
    print('Hello world')
```

Then you add `setup.py` with the following:

```
from setuptools import setup
setup(
    name='myscript',
    version='0.0.1',
    entry_points={
        'console_scripts': [
            'myscript=myscript:run'
        ]
    }
)
```

Entry point format is `terminal_command_name=python_script_name:main_method_name`

Finally install with the following command.

```
pip install -e /path/to/script/folder
```

`-e` stands for editable, meaning you'll be able to work on the script and invoke the latest version without need to reinstall

After that you can run `myscript` from any directory.

Comment: Is it possible to call entry points like `myscript update` or only `myscript_update`

Comment: @NikitaProkaiev In `myscript update`, `update` is a command line argument to the script -- the same as if you ran `python myscript.py update`. It would have no effect unless you wrote code in your script to handle command line arguments. You could define another entry in `console_scripts` like `myscript_update=myscript:update` to call, in this case, a function called `update`.

Comment: if you just have a python script then do `pip install -e .`

Answer (score 12):

I usually do in the script:

```
#!/usr/bin/python
... code ...
```

And in terminal:

```
$: chmod 755 yourfile.py
$: ./yourfile.py
```

[image: permission table]

Comment: avoid hardcoding path to python, prefer ``/usr/bin/env python``

Answer (score 3):

Another related solution which some people may be interested in. One can also directly embed the contents of myscript.py into your .bashrc file on Linux (should also work for MacOS I think)

For example, I have the following function defined in my .bashrc for dumping Python pickles to the terminal, note that the `${1}` is the first argument following the function name:

```py
depickle() {
python << EOPYTHON
import pickle
f = open('${1}', 'rb')
while True:
   try:
      print(pickle.load(f))
   except EOFError:
      break
EOPYTHON
}
```

With this in place (and after reloading .bashrc), I can now run `depickle a.pickle` from any terminal or directory on my computer.

Answer (score 2):

The simplest way that comes to my mind is to use "pyinstaller".

1. create an environment that contains all the lib you have used in your code.
2. activate the environment and in the command window write `pip install pyinstaller`
3. Use the command window to open the main directory that codes maincode.py is located.
4. remember to keep the environment active and write `pyinstaller maincode.py`
5. Check the folder named "build" and you will find the executable file.

I hope that this solution helps you.
GL