# How do I allow SSH access to a Python script without exposing it's source code?

Tags: linux, ubuntu, unix, ssh

What are the steps to configure a user account so when they log in they have the ability to run a python script without having access to the source code of the script itself?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How do I make a python script executable?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27494758/how-do-i-make-a-python-script-executable)

Comment: Combine making the script executable, and then take away read/write permissions.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe try [Nuitka](https://nuitka.net/), it is a Python to C++ converter.


`python -m pip install nuitka
python -m nuitka --mingw64 example.py`