# How do I pass a ROS package to another person?

Tags: ros

I have made a ROS workspace and inside a package.
I did `catkin_make` and everything is working well.

I would like to give this package (or should I give the entire workspace?) to another person.

I am thinking to give him a zip file of the files and folders (it contains launch files, python scripts, rviz files etc) so I am expecting he will unzip it in his machine

I would like he can run the launch files without problems

What is what he needs to do for this? (of course he will have ROS installed, that is no problem)

I am thinking perhaps he should do `source devel/setup.bash` but is this enough?

Comment: A zip-file of the contents of the `src` folder should be sufficient. If you have listed the dependencies inside your `package.xml` they will have to execute [`$ rosdep install`](http://wiki.ros.org/rosdep) and build the workspace with `$ catkin_make` (or `$ catkin build`) and finally source it with `$ source devel/setup.bash`. I can give you a more detailed answer on it (including ways of sharing packages/workspaces with Git and continuous integration and unit testing) later on in the evening.

Comment: @2b-t Thanks. I am looking forward to your answerr

Comment: Did you manage to share your package successfully or do you still have some open questions?

Comment: Due to sudden tasks scheduled at work that made me take an interval, I am going to continue addressing this from friday.  I will have some feedback by then I think

Answer (score 4):

When sharing a workspace with somebody **only the source space [`src`](http://wiki.ros.org/catkin/workspaces) has to be shared**. It should contain all our **packages** with their launch files (`*.launch`), Python (`*.py`) and C++ nodes (`*.cpp`,  `*.hpp`), YAML configuration files (`*.yaml`), RViz configurations (`*.rviz`), robot descriptions (`*.urdf`, `*.xacro`) and describe how each node should be compiled in a `CMakeLists.txt`. Additionally you are supposed to **keep track of all the Debian packages you install inside the `package.xml` file** of each package.

If for some obscure reason there are things that I have to do that can't be accommodated in the standard installation instructions given above, I will actually write a **bash script** that performs these steps for me and add it either to the package itself or the workspace. This way I can automate also more complex steps such as installing OpenCV or modifying the `.bashrc`. Here a small example of what such a minimal script (I generally name them `install_dependencies.sh`) might look like:

```
#!/bin/bash

# Get current workspace
WS_DIR="$(dirname "$(dirname "$(readlink -fm "$0")")")"

# Check if script is run as root '$ sudo ...'
if ["$EUID" -ne 0]
  then
    echo "Error: This script has to be run as root '$ sudo ./install_dependencies.sh'
    exit 1
fi

echo "Installing dependencies..."

# Modify .bashrc
echo "- Modifying '~/.bashrc'..."
echo "source ${WS_DIR}/devel/setup.bash" >> ~/.bashrc

echo ""
echo "Dependencies installed."
```

If for some reason even that is not possible I make always sure to **document it** properly either in a [Markdown `*.md` read-me](https://guides.github.com/features/mastering-markdown/) either in a `/doc` folder inside your package, in the `read-me.md` inside the base folder of your repository or inside the root folder of your workspace.

The receiver then only has to

- [Create a new workspace](http://wiki.ros.org/catkin/Tutorials/create_a_workspace)
- Copy or clone the package files to its `src` folder
- **Install all the Debian package dependencies** listed in the `package.xml` files with [`$ rosdep install`](http://wiki.ros.org/rosdep)
- (If any: Execute the bash scripts I created by hand `$ sudo ./install_dependencies.sh` or perform the steps given in the documentation)
- **Build the workspace** with `$ catkin_make` or [`$ catkin build`](https://catkin-tools.readthedocs.io/en/latest/verbs/catkin_build.html) from catkin-tools
- **Source the current environment variables** with `$ source devel/setup.bash`
- Make sure that the [Python nodes are executable](https://stackoverflow.com/a/27494871/9938686) either by `$ chmod +x <filename>` or right-clicking the corresponding Python nodes (located in `src` or `scripts` of your package), selecting `Properties/Permissions` and enabling `Allow executing file as program`.
- Run the desired Python or C++ nodes (`$ rosrun <package_name> <executable_name>`) and launch files (`$ roslaunch <package_name> <launch_file_name>`)

It is up to you to share the code as a compressed file, in form of a Git repository or a more advanced way (see below) but I will introduce some best practices in the following paragraphs that will pay off in the long run with larger packages.

---

0. **Sharing a package or sharing a workspace?**

One can either share a single package or an entire workspace. I personally think that most of the time one should **share the entire workspace** instead of the package alone even if you only cloned the other packages from a public Github repo. This might save the receiver a lot of headache e.g. when checking out the wrong branch.

1. **Version control with Git**

Arguably the best way to arrange your packages is by using Git. I'd actually make **a repository for every package you create** (if a couple of packages are virtually inseparable you can also bundled them to a single Git repo or better use [metapackages](http://wiki.ros.org/Metapackages)). Then create an additional repository for your workspace and **include your own packages and packages from other sources as [submodules](https://git-scm.com/book/en/v2/Git-Tools-Submodules)**. This allows your code to be modular and re-usable: You can share only a package or the entire workspace!

As a first step I always [add a `.gitignore` file](https://git-scm.com/docs/gitignore) to each package repository which excludes `*.pyc` files and another one to the workspace repository that ignores the `build`, `devel` and `install` folders.

You can add a particular repository as submodule to your workspace Git repository by opening a console inside the `src` folder of your workspace repository and [typing](https://stackoverflow.com/a/15782629/9938686)

```
$ git submodule add -b <branch_name> <git_url_to_package> <optional_directory_rename>
```

Note that you can actually track a particular branch of a repository that you include as a submodule. In case you need a submodule at some point follow [this guide](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1260982/9938686).

If you share the workspace repository with someone they will have to have access to each individual submodule repository and they will have to **not only pull the repository but also update the submodules** with

```
$ git clone --recurse-submodules <git_url_to_workspace_repository>
```

and potentially update them to the latest commit with

```
$ git submodule update --remote
```

After these two steps they should have a full version of the repository with submodules and they should be able to progress with the steps listed in the section above.

1.1 **Unit-testing and continuous integration**

Before sharing a repository you will have to verify that everything is working correctly. This can take a decent amount of time, in particular if the code base is large and you are modifying it frequently. In the ideal case you would have to install it on a brand new machine or inside a virtual box in order to make sure that the set-up works which would take quite some time. This is where [unit testing](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unit_testing) comes into play: For every class and function you program you will write a test. This way you can simply run these tests and make sure everything is working correctly. Generally these unit tests will be performed automatically and the [working branches merged continuously](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Continuous_integration). Generally the test routines are written with the libraries [Boost::Test (C++)](https://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_75_0/libs/test/doc/html/index.html), [GoogleTest (generally used in ROS with C++)](https://github.com/google/googletest), [unittest](https://docs.python.org/3/library/unittest.html) (for Python) and [QtTest](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qttest-index.html) (for GUIs). For ROS launch files there is additionally [rostest](http://wiki.ros.org/rostest). How this can be done in ROS is described [here](http://wiki.ros.org/CIs) and [here](http://wiki.ros.org/Quality/Tutorials/UnitTesting).

2. **ROSjects**

If you do not even want the person you are sending the code to to go through the hassle to set it up you might consider sending them a [ROSject](https://www.theconstructsim.com/welcome-to-rosds/). A ROSject is an **online virtual ROS environment** (by the guys behind [`The Construct`](https://www.theconstructsim.com/), the main source of ROS courses and of ROS tutorials on Youtube) that can be created and shared very easily from your existing Git repository as can be seen [here](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=cR-Ow5K7oSo). The simulation runs entirely in the cloud on a virtual machine. This way the potential of failure is very low but it is not a choice if your code is supposed to run on hardware and not only in simulation.

3. **Docker**

If your installation procedure is complex you might as well use a **container** such as a [Docker](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Docker_(software)).
More information about using Docker in combination with ROS can be found [here](http://wiki.ros.org/docker/Tutorials/Docker). The Docker container might introduce though a bit of overhead and it is probably no choice for code which should have real-time priority in combination with a [real-time patched operating system](https://rt.wiki.kernel.org/index.php/Main_Page).

4. **Debian or snap package**

Another way of sending somebody a ROS package is by packing it into a Debian or snap package. This process takes a while and is in particular favourable if you want to give your code to a large number of users that should use the code out of the box. Instructions on how this can be done for Debian packages can be found [here](https://gist.github.com/awesomebytes/196eab972a94dd8fcdd69adfe3bd1152)  and [here](https://medium.com/@freeleons/generate-deb-installable-package-from-ros-package-b095f319b825), while a guide for snap can be found [here](http://wiki.ros.org/ROS/Tutorials/Packaging%20your%20ROS%20project%20as%20a%20snap).

Comment: Thanks for the great answer. I have upvoted it. I am in the process of creating a package and next week I will share it with my colleague. I will use your recommendations and mark it as an answer then.  Btw, so sharing is all packages inside th `src` directory then, not just one package?

Comment: @KansaiRobot You are welcome. No, you can share a single package as well but generally I would share the entire `src` folder. It never hurts. Later is referred to as "sharing a workspace".