# How to make executable works from python script?

Tags: python, executable

I'm trying to make my python script executable file. However, when I convert it to exe with pyinstaller or py2exe, executable file does not work. I opened in cmd, no error but still does not work as i expected. On the other hand, when I start the actual python script, it works without a problem.

Here is what my folder structure looks like:

- account_details.json
- posts.xls
- actual_python_script.py

What could be the problem and how can I solve this?

Comment: Here is a post on [How do I make a python script executable](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27494758/how-do-i-make-a-python-script-executable) that you might find helpful.

Comment: @Seraph i tried the pyinstaller version but i couldnt be successful with that.