# How to use git filter-repo to format all code in git history

Tags: git, clang-format, git-filter-branch, git-filter-repo

I would like to use [git filter-repo](https://github.com/newren/git-filter-repo) to format all my c++ files in my repos history. To format the files I use `clang-format`.
Doing this with git filter-branch I know that I could do:

```
git filter-branch --tree-filter 'find . -type f -iname \*\.cpp -o -iname \*\.hpp | xargs clang-format -i' HEAD
```

but since git suggests to use git filter-repo instead, I would like to do so.
However it is unclear to me which callback function to use?

Cheers!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Alright, I found my answer at the bottom of [this cheat sheet](https://github.com/newren/git-filter-repo/blob/main/Documentation/converting-from-filter-branch.md#cheat-sheet-conversion-of-examples-from-the-filter-branch-manpage).
There exists already a [lint-history](https://github.com/newren/git-filter-repo/blob/main/contrib/filter-repo-demos/lint-history) script which does exactly that. with a `.clang-format` file in the root of the git repo the following worked nicely

```
lint-history --relevant 'return (filename.endswith(b".cpp") or filename.endswith(b".hpp"))' clang-format -style=file:.clang-format -i
```

Comment: Could you explain how to make the `lint-history` script a command? After saving the file, I can run it with `python lint-history ...`, but how can you get rid of the need for `python`?

Comment: You can do something like https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27494758/how-do-i-make-a-python-script-executable however running the command with or without python infront should not matter?

Comment: Ah, got it. Yes, it works fine with `python`, but it's for the convenience as well as for learning. I had tried `chmod +x` earlier, but I see now that it also needs to be in the `$PATH`. Thank you!