# Is there a way to execute .py scripts from path in windows?

Tags: python, command-prompt

I would like to use a python script anywhere within command prompt. This is possible in unix, but I couldn't find anything for windows. Do I have to convert it to .exe?

Edit: not sure why this is being downvoted, maybe it's a silly question but I can't find any similar threads here and I can't be the first person to want to execute .py scripts from their path...

Edit 2: I think my wording was unclear. I would like to know a method to execute python scripts in Windows without needing to specify `python path/to/script.py` every time. Here is a solution on Linux where the shebang statement invokes the python interpreter, and the script in question can be easily placed in bin: [How do I install a script to run anywhere from the command line?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6967331/how-do-i-install-a-script-to-run-anywhere-from-the-command-line) . Does there exist a solution like this for Windows?

Comment: A Python script is a text file. On Windows you can run it by opening it with the `python.exe` executable (or with a text editor if you want to edit it). In a command prompt you would use `python script.py`. See https://docs.python.org/3.6/using/windows.html.

Comment: I know that you need to use python to run it, I was wondering if there was a way to do this without needing to go `python path/to/script.py` everytime

Comment: Edit: similar solution for linux https://superuser.com/questions/828737/run-python-scripts-without-explicitly-invoking-python

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here's a solution for running `myScript.py`:

1. add to the `myScript.py` file a first line `#!python` (or `#!python3` if you want to use Python 3)

For instance:

```
#!python
import sys
sys.stdout.write("hello from Python %s\n" % (sys.version,))
```

2. change the "*opens with*" property of `myScript.py` to `py.exe` (to find where it is use `where py`-- I have it in `C:\Windows\py.exe`)
3. put the script `myScript.py` somewhere in your Windows path

and now you should be able to type `myScript.py` anywhere in a command prompt and run the Python script with your chosen Python version.

See: https://docs.python.org/3.6/using/windows.html#from-the-command-line

Comment: Awesome this works! Though I cannot import 3rd party modules installed with pip when I run the script from cmd. Any ideas as to why?

Comment: @NullSalad maybe you are mixing the versions, if you installed modules for Python2 they won't be available for Python3 and you need to install another copy with `pip3`