# How do I allow a file to be accessible from all directories?

Tags: python, linux, bash, path

I have a python program which is an interpreter, for a language that I have made. It is called cbc.py, and it is in a certain directory. Now, I want to know how I can call it, along with sys.argv arguments (like python3 cbc.py _FILENAME_TO_RUN_) in any directory. I have done research on the .bashrc file and on the PATH variable, but I can't find anything that really helps me with my problem. Could someone please show me how to resolve my problem?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6967331/how-do-i-install-a-script-to-run-anywhere-from-the-command-line

Answer (score 0):

You need to make your script executable first and then add it to your PATH.
If you have your python script at `~/path/to/your/script/YOUR_SCRIPT_NAME`:

- add `#!/usr/bin/python3` at the top of you script,
- give executable permision to your script using `sudo chmod a+x YOUR_SCRIPT_NAME`,
- edit `~/.bashrc` to add your script path, e.g. `echo PATH="$HOME/path/to/your/script:$PATH" >> ~/.bashrc`,
- restart or re-login or run `source ~/.bashrc`,
- now you can access your script via `YOUR_SCRIPT_NAME` anywhere.

Comment: This isn't working for me. I have added this to the top of my script: https://ibb.co/zZGx9DG I did the sudo chmod command in my terminal, and I added this to my script path: PATH=/Users/caspianahlberg/Users/caspianahlberg/Desktop/Programming/Python\ Files/cowboy/Simple_Shell_Test:/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.7/bin:/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/bin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin:/usr/local/go/bin (by the way, cbc stands for cowboy compiler). But, I just get this error: -bash: cbc.py: command not found - Hm, why isn't it working?

Comment: Here is a sample line to add `/path/to/a/script/myscript.py` to PATH: `echo 'PATH="/path/to/a/script:$PATH"'`

Comment: As I have never used Mac, I am sorry to not answering you correctly.

Comment: That's not how the `PATH` var works. It contains a colon separated list of directories to search for commands. Putting the full path of the command in `PATH` is a no-op; i.e., it doesn't do anything. Also, the python3 binary may, or may not, be */usr/bin/python3*. It could just as easily be */usr/local/bin/python3* or some other directory.

Comment: Then how does it work? What's the point in using the PATH variable?

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately, you can't easily run `python3 cbc.py ...` from a directory unless `cbc.py` is in that directory. But you can easily run `cbc.py ...` from any directory.

Edit `cbc.py` so that the first line is something like this:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python3
```

(ref [Should I put #! (shebang) in Python scripts, and what form should it take?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6908143/should-i-put-shebang-in-python-scripts-and-what-form-should-it-take))

Make cbc.py executable:

```
chmod +x cbc.py
```

Now you should be able to run it without typing python3, but not yet from any directory:

```
./cbc.py ...
```

Next, edit `~/.bashrc` so that the last line is:

```
export PATH:$PATH:...
```

and here, in place of `...`, put the absolute path to the directory containing `cbc.py`.

A standard way of describing that is:

```
export PATH:$PATH:<absolute path to your script's directory>
```

For example (depending on your operating system):

```
export PATH:$PATH:/home/caspian/cbcdir
```

or:

```
# this path has a directory with a space in it's name, so it must go in quotes
export PATH:$PATH:'/Users/CaspianAhlberg/Documents/Cbc Project'
```

or:

```
# this path has a directory with a space and a single quote in it's name,
# so it must go in double-quotes
export PATH:$PATH:"/Users/CaspianAhlberg/Documents/Cbc's Project"
```

or, even more absurdly:

```
# you can also "escape" funny characters using \ instead of
# wrapping the entire string in quotes
export PATH:$PATH:/cygdrive/c/Users/Documents/Cbc\ Project
```

Long story short, don't put spaces nor quotes in directory nor file names.

Now start a new bash shell and try `cbc.py ...`